# Django Slow Database Model Query

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am having issues with the performance of a couple of queries in my Django app... all others are very fast.

I have an Orders model with OrderItems, the query seems to be running much slower than other queries (1-2 seconds, vs. 0.2 seconds). I'm using MySQL backend. In the serializer I do a count to return whether an order has food or drink items, I suspect this is causing the performance hit. Is there a better way to do it?

Here is my models setup for Order and OrderItems

```
class Order(models.Model):
  STATUS = (
       ('1', 'Placed'),
       ('2', 'Complete')
   )
   PAYMENT_STATUS = (
       ('1', 'Pending'),
       ('2', 'Paid'),
       ('3', 'Declined'),
       ('4', 'Manual')

   )
   shop= models.ForeignKey(Shop,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2,default=0)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
   time_completed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True,blank=True)
   time_cancelled = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True,blank=True)
   status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS, default='1',)
   payment_method =  models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PAYMENT_METHOD, default='3',)
   payment_status =  models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PAYMENT_STATUS, default='1',)
   type =  models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPE, default='1',)

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.id)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
   order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='DRINK')
   drink = models.ForeignKey(
       Drink,
       blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
   )
   food = models.ForeignKey(
       Food,
       blank=True,
       null=True,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
   )
   quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2,default=0)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
   delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.id)
```

In my rest order serializer, here is the query for get,

queryset = Order.objects.filter(shop=shop,status__in=['1','2'],payment_status__in=['2','4'])

The serializer is below, but this query is quite slow. I assume because I am doing a count() on OrderItems - is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
class OrderOverviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   tabledetails = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   has_food = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   has_drink = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


   class Meta:
       model = Order
       fields = ['id','total_price', 'created_at','has_food','has_drink','type','status','shop','table','customer','shopdetails']

   def get_shopdetails(self, instance):
       qs = Shop.objects.get(id=instance.shop.id)
       serializer = ShopSerializer(instance=qs, many=False)
       return serializer.data


   def get_has_food(self, obj):
       foodCount = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=obj.id,type='FOOD').count()
       return foodCount

   def get_has_drink(self, obj):
       drinkCount = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=obj.id,type='DRINK').count()
       return drinkCount
```

Comment: Validate your hypothesis first: does it become faster if you make `get_has_food()` and `get_has_drink()` always return e.g. 0?

Comment: If I run it on my localhost, as is - 1140 ms, with a hardcoding count return of 0... 1150ms.. so it looks like I'm off the mark on my theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should consider `db_index=True` on the fields you're querying over (`Order.status`, `Order.payment_status`, `OrderItem.type`).
- `get_shopdetails()` isn't used for anything in the serializer? (On a similar note, the getter for `tabledetails` is missing... are you maybe presenting some code that's not exactly what you're running?)

  - `get_shopdetails()` is redundant anyway; you can simply declare `shop = ShopSerializer()` and DRF will know what to do.
- If the `get_has_food`/`get_has_drink` fields did prove to be the bottleneck (which they apparently didn't), you could use a Django aggregate to count the rows during the query for orders.
- Speaking of, your serializer is accessing several foreign keys, which will all cause N+1 queries; you can add `.select_related('shop', 'customer', 'table')` (or `.prefetch_related()` the same) at the very least to have those get loaded in one fell swoop.

Beyond this -- profile your code! The easiest way to do that is to copy the skeleton from `manage.py` and add some code to simulate your query, e.g. (this is dry-coded):

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_settings")
import django
django.setup()
from django.test import TestClient
c = TestClient()
for x in range(15):
   c.get("/api/order/")  # TODO: use correct URL
```

and run your script with

```
python -m cProfile my_test_script.py
```

You'll see which functions end up taking the most time.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, using the prefetch and the the ShopSerializer reduced the SQL count from 43 to 23, but there are still two count(*) to get the has_food and has_drink. I'm looking at the docs for Aggregate, but I can't see how I can aggregate and use a where clause, i.e. .queryset = Order.objects.filter(shop=shop,status__in=['1','6','7'],payment_status__in=['2','4']).select_related('table').annotate(has_food=Count('OrderItem', type='FOOD'))

Comment: `Count` and other aggregates accept a `filter=` parameter (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#id8): `.annotate(food_count=Count('OrderItem', filter=Q(type='FOOD')))`

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm almost there- 3 queries!! For some reason the above is trying to do the filter by type on the parent order and not the orderitem table, see....  COUNT(CASE
                 WHEN `website_order`.`type` = 'FOOD' THEN `website_orderitem`.`id`
                 ELSE NULL
             END) AS `has_food`,

Comment: Try `orderitem__type`?

Answer (score 2):

There reason for that is famous [N+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping) problem that Django `ORM` is so inept to handle. The solution for it is to use [select_related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388668/how-to-avoid-n1-select-in-django) answerd in this question. More on that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNn40ut8z6Y).

Comment: I wouldn't say Django ORM is inept at N+1 - you just have to opt-in to select_related or prefetch_related, it doesn't do it magically...

Comment: I back this answer, profile your queries using `django_silk`, see how many queries it makes for a request, are those many queries really necessary?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. This looks promising... I am not sure how I would utilise that in my DRF setup though, has_food and has_drink are dynamic columns..

Comment: If you run it through the profiler-- `django_silk`-- it gives you a full profile for the python code, and the queries executed-- you'll definitely be able to identify the bottleneck and address it.

Comment: Here is this problem explained very well with [Djano example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNn40ut8z6Y)