# How to get a specific queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am building a hospital management app and I am currently building the Nurse's webpage. In that webpage, I would like the following to display: a list of all employed nurses, a list of their workshifts, and what departments they work for.

I am trying to get the department section to display but I keep getting an error "too many values to unpack (expected 2)".

What can I do so that the nurses' department shows?

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

#Work Related aka Department and Work Shift

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class WorkShift(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

#Personel Related aka Employees and Patients

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work_shift = models.OneToOneField(WorkShift, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Nurse(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    sector = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reports_to = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work_shift = models.OneToOneField(WorkShift, default="", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class Patient(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Sick', 'Sick'),
        ('Healing', 'Healing'),
        ('Cured', 'Cured'),
        ('Deceased', 'Deceased'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, choices=STATUS)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, default="", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    care = models.ForeignKey(Nurse, default="", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
```

Views.py

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Doctor, Nurse, Patient, Department, WorkShift
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import DoctorForm, NurseForm, PatientForm

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    patient = Patient.objects.all()
    nurse = Nurse.objects.all()
    doctor = Doctor.objects.all()
    department = Department.objects.all()

    total_patient = patient.count()
    sick = patient.filter(status='Sick').count()
    healing = patient.filter(status='Healing').count()
    cured = patient.filter(status='Cured').count()

    total_nurse = nurse.count()

    # if request.method == 'POST':
    #     form = 

    context = {
        'patient':patient, 'nurse':nurse,
        'doctor':doctor, 'total_patient':total_patient,
        'sick':sick, 'healing':healing, 'cured':cured,
        'total_nurse':total_nurse,
        'department':department
    }

    return render(request, 'lifesaver/index.html', context)

#All Patient Related

def patient(request):
    patient = Patient.objects.all()

    context = {'patient':patient}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/patient.html', context)

def patient_add(request):

    patient = Patient.objects.all()
    form = PatientForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PatientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Patient Form is Valid")
            form.save()
        else:
            print("Patient Form is Invalid")
            print(form.errors)
        return redirect('patient')

    context = {'form':form,}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/patient_add.html', context)

def patient_update(request, pk):

    patient = Patient.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = PatientForm(instance=patient)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PatientForm(request.POST, instance=patient)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Update completed')
            form.save()
            return redirect('patient')
        else:
            print('Update not completed')
            print(form.errors)
            
    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'lifesaver/patient_update.html', context)

#All Doctor Related

def doctor(request):

    doctor = Doctor.object.all()

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/doctor.html', context)

def doctor_add(request):
    
    doctor = Doctor.object.all()
    form = DoctorForm()

    context = {'doctor':doctor, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/doctor')

def doctor_update(request):

    doctor = Doctor.object.all()
    form = DoctorForm()

    context = {'doctor':doctor, 'form':form}

# Nurse Related

def nurse(request):
    nurse = Nurse.objects.all()
    workshift = WorkShift.objects.all()
    department = Nurse.objects.get('sector')

    context = {'nurse':nurse, 'workshift':workshift, 'department':department}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/nurse.html', context)
    

def nurse_add(request):
    nurse = Nurse.objects.all()
    form = NurseForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NurseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Nurse Form is Valid")
            form.save()
        else:
            print("Nurse Form is Invalid")
            print(form.errors)
        return redirect('nurse')

    context = {'form':form,}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/nurse_add.html', context)

def nurse_update(request):
    nurse = Nurse.objects.all()
    form = NurseForm()

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/nurse_update.html', context)

#Work Related

def department(request):
    department = Department.objects.all()

    context = {'department':department}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/department.html', context)
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Doctor, Nurse, Patient, Department, WorkShift
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class DoctorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = 
    {

            'placeholder': 'Add a New Doctor',
            'class': 'form-control'
    }
    ))

    department = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Department.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs=
    {
            'class': 'selectpicker',
            'placeholder': 'Department', 
    }
    )) 

    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ['name', 'department']

class NurseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = 
    {

            'placeholder': 'Add a New Nurse',
            'class': 'form-control'
    }
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = Nurse
        fields = ['name']

class PatientForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = 
    {

            'placeholder': 'Add a New Nurse',
            'class': 'form-control'
    }
    ))

    description = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs =
    {
            'placeholder': "Describe the patient's symptoms",
            'class': 'form-control'
    }
    ))

    department = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Department.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs=
    {
            'class': 'selectpicker',
            'placeholder': 'Select Department', 
    }
    )) 

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'department', 'care', 'status']

#Work Related

class WorkShiftForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
                model = WorkShift
                fields = '__all__'
```

Nurse.html

```
{% extends 'lifesaver/main.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for nurse in nurse %}
    {{nurse.name}}
    {{nurse.report_to}}
    {{nurse.care}}
    {{nurse.work_shift}}
    {{department}}
{% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

[image: Value Error]

Comment: for which line you are getting error?

Comment: @404pio I get an error for this line: department = Nurse.objects.get('sector')

Comment: good. And what is the syntax of getting single object via Django ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In models.py, Nurse object has field 'sector' which is a Foreign Key to a Department record.  So part of the problem is you're trying to output the wrong field name in your template as there is no actual `department` field defined on Nurse model.

Try these edits to views.py:
`nurses = Nurse.objects.all()`
then in your context: `context = {..., 'nurses': nurses, ...}`

Then in nurse.html:

```
{% for nurse in nurses: %}
   ...
   {{ nurse.sector.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

That should at least get your nurse objects rendered in the template. But you have a potential issue in calling `nurse.sector` when that FK is defined in the Nurse model with `null=True`.  So a better practice would be to define an accessor method in the Nurse model to check if `sector` is present before calling it's `name`, i.e.:

```
# in Nurse model
def department_name(self):
    if self.sector_id:
        return self.sector.name
    else:
        return '' # or some other default
```

Then you could edit nurse.html again replacing my code above with:

```
{% for nurse in nurses: %}
   ...
   {{ nurse.department_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is just scratching the surface of how you could handle this but it hopefully answers your question and prevents a common error once you make these edits.

You'll also probably want to look into [Django QuerySet API's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) `select_related()` and `prefetch_related()` methods to avoid N+1 query issues that are possible in your current code.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388668/how-to-avoid-n1-select-in-django) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping) for more background.

So for example, to avoid N+1, instead of calling `nurses = Nurse.objects.all()` instead do `nurses = Nurse.objects.select_related('sector').all()`.  That will do a join to the Department model on the FK.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/97308/417212) to one of the above N+1 questions has more details.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a field and a value, e.g.

```
  Nurse.objects.get('sector' = 'dentistry')
```

or if you want to display a specific nurses department you would use this in your template:

```
{{nurse.department.name}}
```

Comment: I've attempted both but I get errors for both. For the first one, I get a "cannot unpack non-iterable bool object" error and for the second one, the original error persists

Comment: for the second one can you remove the department queryset and try again?

Comment: do you mean writing {{nurse.name}}? or {{nurse.department}}?

Comment: the whole thing, {{ nurse.department.name }}